# Join en DataTable si el campo a unir contiene la cadena (Join if contains)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql, datatable, visual

¡Hola buen día!, estoy intentando realizar un Join en un DataTable como Enumerable mediante C# a través del método del mismo (.Join) pero este metodo regresa la coincidencia exacta y busco que me regrese los valores si la segunda tabla los contiene dentro del campo, ejemplo

Campo A: `John`
Campo B: `0Johnathan`

Resultado del Join:

`------------------------
|  John    | Johnathan |`

Espero haberme explicado bien, ¡saludos!

EDIT: Les adjunto una parte del código que he trabajado para la coincidencia exacta

```
 dt_Empleados.AsEnumerable().
                Join(dt_Empleados2.AsEnumerable(),
                        db1_row => db1_row.ItemArray[4], //ID
                        db2_row => db2_row.ItemArray[0], //ID justo aqui me gustaría descubrir si ese ID puede estar entre caracteres o numeros
                (db1_row, db2_row) => new { db1_row, db2_row }).ToList().
                ForEach(o =>
                    o.db1_row.SetField(8, o.db2_row.ItemArray[1] //Se modifica x dato
                    ));
```

Comment: Coloca el codigo para poder ayudar

Comment: @RamiroBarone listo! Una disculpa, saludos :)

Comment: quien llena ese data table?

Comment: @RamiroBarone se llena desde un txt separado por comas (csv)